# rails 4 model text regex allow 0-9, a-z, links and email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, model-validation

I am working with the following model validation and my tests are working except when I started adding the ability to include links bad characters are making it through :(

```
  validates :application_process,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: %r{\A[\w\d .,:/-@&?]+\z}, message: :bad_format }
```

I want to allow the following:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- ?
- :
- /
- @
- .
- ,

Comment: Your hyphen creates a range. Escape it or place at the end of the character class (before `]`) if you need to match a literal hyphen.

Comment: awesome! if you want to add that as an answer I want to give you credit @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have contains a `-`. A hyphen inside a character class creates a range if it is not escaped and does not appear after a shorthand character class, a range, start or end of the character class.

So,  if you need to match a literal hyphen escape it or place at the end of the character class (before `]`).

To only match the characters and ranges you specify in the question, use

```
%r{\A[A-Za-z0-9?:/@.,]+\z}
```

To add a hyphen:

```
%r{\A[A-Za-z0-9?:/@.,-]+\z}
                     ^
```